# How do I make my bot automatically create the channels and roles required for my bot to work as soon as it joins a server?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I do know how to make my bot create a role and a channel. But what is the event called when my bot is added to a server? thats all I want to know (the event name when my bot joins a server) I tried searching up in the documentations of discord.js but only got .createdAt and .createdTimestamp which will just give me the time when the guild was created.

Comment: The ws event emitted is `GUILD_CREATE`. The client event is `guildCreate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emitted event is [`guildCreate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate). This provides the guild joined as the first, and only parameter. Your code should be like this:

```js
client.on("guildCreate", async (guild) => {
  //guild is an instance of Guild which the client has joined
})
```

Comment: hey can you tell me more about guild here, I have ran into errors after doing Discord.guild.roles.create that cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

Comment: You have to do `guild.roles.create` (not with `discord`)

Comment: doing guild.roles.create it gives the error guild is not defined

Comment: I don’t know how your event handler works, but I suspect you didn’t create it properly.

Comment: Ohh no no it works fine as a matter of fact i fixed it, guess what the problem was...... }) legit.